# array of not duplicated elements

Tags: visual-c++

I need to have array of elements that are not duplicated. That means if element is in the list then new value will be skipped from array. Are there any standard types that might be useful in this case (vector, map, etc...)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [set](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/set/set/) to avoid duplicates.

Comment: Another good choice and possibly better than the hash.  To OP, please research both to decide what's most appropriate for your needs.  The answer will hinge on how you want to access the data, and the things you want to do with them.

Comment: -1 for cplusplus.com. It is known to contain many errors and promoting wrong programming practices.

Comment: @jons34yp please recommend us a better site! :)

Answer (score 0):

Hash tables can do this. You have some choices, both standard and MS specific.

Take a look at std::map for a start:

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/